# Fetch data from google spread-sheet with each row as a single sentence

Tags: php

I am going through a very critical situation where I cannot find bright ideas to work upon.

1. I have an Google spread sheet which contains few rows and columns.
2. I want to combine the row together including its column value.(1 row with four columns which results to a single sentence)
3. Simultaneously each row should form a single sentence from the Google spread sheet.

My spread sheet path: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z7_oRxlTIiKIND89sAXHbyTsz1mrTMNwejqkfk8y5P0/edit#gid=0

I don't know how to start of with this and which function, code to prefer ?
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Your spread sheet is private. Accessing not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly:

1. Go to your Spreadsheet in Google Drive.
2. Go to files then "Publish on the Web"
3. Select your worksheet and enable update on the checkbox.
4. In the same box you can get a csv link to your spreadsheet.

Afterwards, just use the "fgetcsv" php function.

```
<php
$url = "http.... url of your csv spreadsheet";
if ( ($handle = fopen($url, "r") ) !== FALSE ) {

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

            $spreadsheet_data[]=$data;
            // HERE the processing

        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
else
    die("Reading not possible.");
?>
```